# How to make a Jar file out of a Java Program

Tags: java

I want to design a small Java Program(Swings), Which will take some input as text and after pressing a JButton, creates a jar file in the output..

Hope i have given enough information..

Thanks a Lot!!.

Comment: No, you haven't. What will be in the output jar ? What will you use the input for ? And start to accept some answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 1):

use this for a file such as xyz.java
jar cfe xyz.jar xyz *.class;
in the command prompt after making the .class file....

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JarOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarOutputStream.html)